# Card shadow and elevation shown in Preview but not shown when app runs

Tags: android, shadow, cardview

I tried to implement `CardView` in my layout.
Here is my code structure upto my card :-

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/activities_bg_color"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start"
    android:focusable="true">

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/coMain"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/includeToolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar" />

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/swiperefresh"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:id="@+id/cvRecent"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
                    app:cardElevation="4dp"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
                    app:contentPadding="4dp"
                    android:layout_margin="8dp">

                    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                        android:id="@+id/clRecent"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
```

The actual problem is that **I am able to see the card properly in preview, but when I run my app card shadow and elevation is not visible**. I tried on Actual Device (Android M) and also with Emulator (Android O).

Any kind of suggestion or help is highly appreciated.

Comment: post your full xml

Answer (score 0):

Did a lots of RnD to solve the issue, finally got it working. I don't know how can this be possible, but I removed 1 line from `Manifest.xml` and the line was

```
    android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
```

I don't understand how can this line have impact on `CardView` shadows.